# QuickActionApi - Unable to select SendEmail on custom object page

Tags: lightning, custom-object, quickaction, lightning-quickaction

I am trying to initiate the SendEmail quick action from a button on my lightning record page.
This seems to work for Account, but does not work for custom objects.
Code is as follows

Component

```
<aura:component description="SendCandidateToOffice" implements="force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,force:hasRecordId,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasSObjectName" access="global">
<lightning:quickActionAPI aura:id="quickActionAPI"/>
<!-- function is doInit, this will be automated in future from a custom quick action -->
<lightning:button value="{!this}" onclick="{!c.doInit}" label="initQa"/></aura:component>
```

Component

```
({
doInit : function(component, event, helper){
    var actionAPI = component.find("quickActionAPI");
    // check available actions
    actionAPI.getAvailableActions().then(function(result){
        console.log("AvailableActions => ", JSON.stringify(result));
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        console.error("ERROR => ", err);
    });

    var args = {actionName: "SendEmail", recordId: component.get("v.recordId")};
    actionAPI.selectAction(args).then(function(result){
        console.log("SendEmail => ", JSON.stringify(result));
    }).catch(function(err){
        console.error("ERROR args => ", err.errors);
    });
}});
```

When I execute this on the account record page, it opens the SendEmail action inside the activities component and the available actions get logged.

[image: desired functionality]

When I do this on a custom object record, the available actions don't get logged and I receive following error; "The action you specified isn’t available on the current record page."

'getAvailableActions()' doesn't seem to do anything, but the 'SendEmail' QuickAction is available on the record page.

[image]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a part of the following known issue; https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001PYcdQAG